# Socket Receive data not completed

Tags: c#, sockets

I wrote simple socket that Send specific request to internet server and receive response
but i have problem when the request sent and socket go to receive mode result of return value
is not complete for example only 1075 byte of 25000 byte receive .

```
Socket skt = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
skt.Connect(hdr.Host, 80);

byte[] req_as_bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(RequestParam);
SentLength = skt.Send(req_as_bytes);
skt.Send(Data, SocketFlags.None);

ReturnLength = skt.Receive(Data);

skt.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
skt.Close();
```

but when i put a sleep before skt.recive() data complitly recive from server like this code

```
Socket skt = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream,             ProtocolType.Tcp);
skt.Connect(hdr.Host, 80);
byte[] req_as_bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(RequestParam);
SentLength = skt.Send(req_as_bytes);
skt.Send(Data, SocketFlags.None);

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);

ReturnLength = skt.Receive(Data);

skt.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
skt.Close();
```

what is the best solution for solving this problem

Answer (score 3):

socket.Receive returns the number of data read. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s4y8aff.aspx

You should check `ReturnLength` and loop till your expected data is received.

TCP is a stream oriented protocol. You will receive the data in the order you send but it doesn't guarentee the data blocks sent and received will be equal.

Comment: when i loop in receive after first receive throw exception "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

Comment: do
    {
    
    a = skt.Receive(Data, ReturnLength, 500 * i - ReturnLength, SocketFlags.None);
    skt.Receive(Data);
    ReturnLength += a;
    i++;

    }
    while (a != 0);

Comment: @Moharrer probably sender closes the connection before reader gets all the data. you should device some protocol to sync them. E.g, send data length,send data, wait for OK etc.

Comment: thank you very much , but for example i get request from firefox to www.yahoo.com . i can't sync myself with yahoo :)

Comment: @Moharrer If you really want to comunicate with a web server using pure tcp sockets, then you should read about [http protocol](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html)(on top of TCP). If you want to implement it fully, I can assure you It will be a pain in the *ss. I would recommend using `WebClient` or `HttpWebRequest` classes for this.